# Plot of integral of summed `Sinc` series is incorrect

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

I have curve given by summing a small, finite series of `Sinc` functions, and I want to plot both the curve and its integral. In principle, it's easy:

```
test[x_] := Sinc[Pi*x]^2 + Sinc[Pi*(x - 3)]^2 + Sinc[Pi*(x - 6)]^2 + 
 Sinc[Pi*(x - 9)]^2 + Sinc[Pi*(x - 12)]^2 + Sinc[Pi*(x - 15)]^2;
sumtest = Integrate[test[x], x]; 
Plot[{test[x], sumtest}, {x, 0, 15}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

...but in practice, it's not working. Since the `Sinc` functions are all squared, the curve is necessarily positive at all points for real `x`. Therefore, the integral is also always positive. But my plot looks like this:

[image: <code>Sinc^2</code> in blue, integral in orange]

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong - and how to do it right?

Comment: `Integrate[test[x], x]` will give you only one of many possible antiderivatives, and not necessarily the one you want. You need an extra condition that will impose your positivity requirement.

Comment: OK. How do I do that?

Comment: You seem to be starting from $0$, so try subtracting the result of `Limit[Integrate[test[x], x], x -> 0]` to your integral.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you. Want to promote your response to 'answer' so I can tick it?

Comment: If I may: if you understand what `Limit[Integrate[test[x], x], x -> 0]` was supposed to compute, I encourage you to try writing an answer to your own question. :) I can then refine it if needed and maybe even upvote it.

Comment: I understand but only kind of. Correct me if I'm wrong: the limit of the integral as `x->0` has clearly been evaluated by MMA as `-2.3`(ish) - that is the assumption it has chosen for the constant of integration - presumably because the curve then crosses the zero line about mid-way through the plot. By subtracting the value of that assumed constant of integration at `x=0`, you force the constant to become, in effect, `0`... Is that right?

Comment: Since the result of  `Integrate[]` is some function $F(x)$, and $F(0)$ is not zero as you seem to expect it to be, you subtract it from the original function. `Limit[]` is used because an indeterminate form is involved.

Comment: OK, I'll attempt an answer, but it may be a bit muddled...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the generous input of @J.M. is somewhat okay, here is the answer:

I got mixed between definite and indefinite integrals (or antiderivatives). As a result, I wrote a formula that gave the generalised integral (antiderivative) rather than the partial integral specifically between `x=0` and the end-point of the plot at `x=15`. I didn't spot that I'd made this assumption - and MMA, faced with an infinite range of equally valid assumptions about what constant to add to the antiderivative, chose a different number.

Subtracting a `Limit[]` as `x->0` corrects for this:

```
test[x_] := Sinc[Pi*x]^2 + Sinc[Pi*(x - 3)]^2 + Sinc[Pi*(x - 6)]^2 + 
 Sinc[Pi*(x - 9)]^2 + Sinc[Pi*(x - 12)]^2 + Sinc[Pi*(x - 15)]^2;
sumtest = Integrate[test[x], x]-Limit[Integrate[test[x], x], x -> 0]; 
Plot[{test[x], sumtest}, {x, 0, 15}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Comment: Very minor nit: `Integrate[]` happened to give one possible antiderivative among infinitely many choices. Or put differently: `Integrate[]` gave you *an* antiderivative, but not the one you wanted where $F(0)=0$.

Comment: Noted and changed. Thanks JM :-)

Comment: Or use `sumtest[x_] = Assuming[x > 0, Integrate[test[t], {t, 0, x}]]`